Are questions about build failures in Linux kernel sources provided by Android vendors on-topic?
I have some old Android vendor Linux sources that I want to build, but with recent toolchains the kernel fails to build with an error. Are questions about how to build Linux kernel sources provided by Android vendors on-topic for Android Enthusiasts?
